# Perform API calls to WS in jest tests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

Is it possible to perform api calls in jest tests? I don't want to mock the data, i'd like to perform a concrete api requests. I'm using superagent/axios but it always fail when runs in jest tests.

This is the test file

```
import * as request from 'superagent';
test('Expected undefined', () => {
    console.log('START');
    expect.assertions(1);
    request.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Response -> ',JSON.stringify(data));
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error -> ', err);
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        });
    console.log('END');
});
```

and this is the error

```
Expected undefined

    expect.assertions(1)

    Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

      at extractExpectedAssertionsErrors (node_modules/expect/build/extract_expected_assertions_errors.js:46:19)
```

in console

```
START
END
```

Regards

Comment: Add your code and perhaps someone can help

Comment: Yes you can do api request inside jest functions. Show us your code, i guess there is something else wrong

Comment: Added code, it is a common http request. If put the same code in a new file (without 'test' wrapper) and start it with node command, it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey @Premier you need to make your test asynchronous as the request is a promise. There are a few approaches to tell jest to wait for your request to finish. Take a look at the jest docs for testing async functions: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html

`async`/`await`:

```
test('Expected undefined', async () => {
  console.log('START');
  expect.assertions(1);
  await request.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Response -> ',JSON.stringify(data));
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error -> ', err);
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
  console.log('END');
});
```

return the promise

```
test('Expected undefined', () => {
  console.log('START');
  expect.assertions(1);
  return request.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Response -> ',JSON.stringify(data));
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error -> ', err);
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Use `done` callback

```
test('Expected undefined', (done) => {
  console.log('START');
  expect.assertions(1);
  request.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Response -> ',JSON.stringify(data));
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error -> ', err);
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      done(err);
    });
  console.log('END');
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you i forgot the return statement. It works

Comment: Your async code doesn't need to use nested promises.

You could just use `var data = await request.get(...)` and you could also use a normal `try { ... } catch (err) { ... }` block to catch promise rejections.